# QPrinter.setDuplex(QPrinter.duplexLongSide) not working

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am attempting to print a 2-page in duplex mode (DuplexLongSide) but even after setting the printer settings prior to instantiating the dialog, and then confirming the duplex settings are correct after QPrintDialog.Accepted, the prints still come out simplex. I've confirmed that the drive on my Windows 10 host supports duplex printing and the network printer I'm using supports double-sided printing as well. Per musicamante's comments Aug 18, I've updated the routine as is shown below:

```
@logger.catch
def printDialog(self, bDummy):
   if (True == td.__Debug__):
      logger.info(f"TestResultsMainWindow: printDialog...bDummy:{bDummy}")
   #end td.__Debug__

   # Give the user a QPrintDialog to allow them to print the currently-displayed
   # results from the active tab.
   #printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
   printer = QPrinter()
   printer.setDoubleSidedPrinting(True)
   #printer.setDuplex(QPrinter.DuplexAuto)
   printer.setDuplex(QPrinter.DuplexLongSide)
   printer.setResolution(self.DefaultPrintDotsPerInch)

   if (printer.doubleSidedPrinting()):
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug("QPrinter: doubleSidedPrinting printing!")
      #end td.__Debug__
   else:
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug("QPrinter: singleSidedPrinting printing!")
      #end td.__Debug__
   #end if (printer.doubleSidedPrinting())
   if (True == td.__Debug__):
      logger.debug(f"QPrinter mode: {printer.duplex()}")
   #end td.__Debug__

   # Instantiate the dialog with the current printer settings
   dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self.mainWindow)

   if (dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted):

      if (printer.doubleSidedPrinting()):
         if (True == td.__Debug__):
            logger.debug("Check again...QPrinter: doubleSidedPrinting printing!")
         #end td.__Debug__
      else:
         if (True == td.__Debug__):
            logger.debug("Check again...QPrinter: singleSidedPrinting printing!")
         #end td.__Debug__
      #end if (printer.doubleSidedPrinting())
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug(f"Check again...QPrinter mode: {printer.duplex()}")
      #end td.__Debug__

      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug(f"{self.name}: create pixmap of the currently-displayed results and send it to the printer")
      #end td.__Debug__
      # Open the PDF...
      tmpPdfFileHandle = fitz.open(self.pdfFilename)
      mat = fitz.Matrix(self.ImagePrintZoomX, self.ImagePrintZoomY) # zoom factor 1.25x in each direction
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug(f"printDialog: NumPages of {self.pdfFilename} is {len(tmpPdfFileHandle)}")
      #end td.__Debug__

      painter = QtGui.QPainter()
      # We're beginning to print a new page on the printer...
      #printer.newPage()
      for pdfPage in tmpPdfFileHandle:

         # Get the page itself
         pagePixmap = pdfPage.get_pixmap(matrix=mat, alpha=False) # render the page to an image that can be printed
         #pagePixmap = pdfPage.getPixmap(alpha=False) # render the page to an image that can be printed
         pagePixmap.save("page-%i.png" % pdfPage.number)

         # Now convert to PyQt5 QImage
         image=QImage(pagePixmap.samples,
                      pagePixmap.width, pagePixmap.height,
                      pagePixmap.stride, # length of one image line in bytes
                      QImage.Format_RGB888)

         # Convert the image to a PyQt5 QPixmap
         qt5Pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)

         # Now print the page
         #painter = QtGui.QPainter()
         painter.begin(printer)
         # Send the page to the printer...
         painter.drawImage(10, 30, qt5Pixmap.toImage())
         # We're done sending this page to the printer...
         painter.end()
      #end for pdfPage in tmpPdfFileHandle
   else:
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.info(f"{self.name}: printDialog...canceled the print")
      #end td.__Debug__
   #end if (dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted)
#end printDialog()
```

Here is what I see once I select the "Print" button in the print dialog:

2022-08-24 09:36:57.940 | DEBUG    | lruTestDriver:printDialog:633 - QPrinter: doubleSidedPrinting printing!
2022-08-24 09:36:59.297 | DEBUG    | lruTestDriver:printDialog:641 - QPrinter mode: 2
2022-08-24 09:37:05.361 | DEBUG    | lruTestDriver:printDialog:651 - Check again...QPrinter: doubleSidedPrinting printing!
2022-08-24 09:37:07.087 | DEBUG    | lruTestDriver:printDialog:659 - Check again...QPrinter mode: 2
2022-08-24 09:37:08.429 | DEBUG    | lruTestDriver:printDialog:663 - TestResultsMainWindow: create pixmap of the currently-displayed results and send it to the printer
2022-08-24 09:37:10.537 | DEBUG    | lruTestDriver:printDialog:669 - printDialog: NumPages of br549_TestResults_2022-08-24_09-36-31.pdf is 2

Comment: Set those properties *before* creating the dialog and also check for them *after* showing it. Also ensure that the duplex printing is actually supported by the driver. Finally, `if (True == obj.someProperty()):` is unnecessary (and potentially wrong), just use `if obj.someProperty():` if you know that the getter function returns a truthfulness value. This also means that you can normally just do `if dialog.exec():` (unless it's known that exec returns a different value type or a non "bool-able" result, like in QMessageBox).

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this issue was to use the QPrinter.newPage() method. This method essentially either flips the page on the printer (if printing duplex) or feeds another paper into the printer (if printing simplex). Also notice that the QPainter.begin() and QPainter.end() methods are outside the for loop since everything in the for loop is to be printed.

```
@logger.catch
def printDialog(self, bDummy):
   if (True == td.__Debug__):
      logger.info(f"TestResultsMainWindow: printDialog...bDummy:{bDummy}")
   #end td.__Debug__

   # Give the user a QPrintDialog to allow them to print the currently-displayed
   # results from the active tab.
   printer = QPrinter()
   printer.setDoubleSidedPrinting(True)
   printer.setDuplex(QPrinter.DuplexLongSide)
   printer.setResolution(self.DefaultPrintDotsPerInch)

   if (printer.doubleSidedPrinting()):
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug("QPrinter: doubleSidedPrinting printing!")
      #end td.__Debug__
   else:
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug("QPrinter: singleSidedPrinting printing!")
      #end td.__Debug__
   #end if (printer.doubleSidedPrinting())
   if (True == td.__Debug__):
      logger.debug(f"QPrinter mode: {printer.duplex()}")
   #end td.__Debug__

   # Instantiate the dialog
   dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self.mainWindow)

   if (dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted):

      if (printer.doubleSidedPrinting()):
         if (True == td.__Debug__):
            logger.debug("Check again...QPrinter: doubleSidedPrinting printing!")
         #end td.__Debug__
      else:
         if (True == td.__Debug__):
            logger.debug("Check again...QPrinter: singleSidedPrinting printing!")
         #end td.__Debug__
      #end if (printer.doubleSidedPrinting())
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug(f"Check again...QPrinter mode: {printer.duplex()}")
      #end td.__Debug__

      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug(f"{self.name}: create pixmap of the currently-displayed results and send it to the printer")
      #end td.__Debug__
      # Open the PDF...
      tmpPdfFileHandle = fitz.open(self.pdfFilename)
      mat = fitz.Matrix(self.ImagePrintZoomX, self.ImagePrintZoomY) # zoom factor 1.25x in each direction
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.debug(f"printDialog: NumPages of {self.pdfFilename} is {len(tmpPdfFileHandle)}")
      #end td.__Debug__

      painter = QtGui.QPainter()
      # We're beginning to print a new page on the printer...
      painter.begin(printer)
      page = 1
      for pdfPage in tmpPdfFileHandle:

         # Get the page itself
         pagePixmap = pdfPage.get_pixmap(matrix=mat, alpha=False) # render the page to an image that can be printed
         #pagePixmap = pdfPage.getPixmap(alpha=False) # render the page to an image that can be printed
         pagePixmap.save("page-%i.png" % pdfPage.number)

         # Now convert to PyQt5 QImage
         image=QImage(pagePixmap.samples,
                      pagePixmap.width, pagePixmap.height,
                      pagePixmap.stride, # length of one image line in bytes
                      QImage.Format_RGB888)

         # Convert the image to a PyQt5 QPixmap
         qt5Pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)

         # Send the image to the printer...
         painter.drawImage(10, 30, qt5Pixmap.toImage())
         # We're done sending this page to the printer...
         if (len(tmpPdfFileHandle) > page):
             # Assume 1 side of a page per image. If duplex printing is set
             # then newPage() will cause printing to the other side
             printer.newPage()
             page = page + 1
      #end for pdfPage in tmpPdfFileHandle
      painter.end()
   else:
      if (True == td.__Debug__):
         logger.info(f"{self.name}: printDialog...canceled the print")
      #end td.__Debug__
   #end if (dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted)
#end printDialog()
```